# correct usage of the VERSIONINFO resource

Tags: c++, visual-c++, versioninfo, application-name

I have set up my version table info in my version.rc file as follows:

```
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
|       Key       |                  Value                  |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
|   CompanyName   | MyCompany
| FileDescription | A test application that does something. |
|  InternalName   | TestApp                                 |
|   FileVersion   | 1.0.0                                   |
| OriginalFilename| TestApp.exe
|  ProductVersion | 1.0.0                                   |
|   ProductName   | Test Application                        |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Whenever my application crashes or some antivirus message pops up asking for permission or basically any event that displays my application name occurs, the application name is displayed as **"A test application that does something"**, i.e. `FileDescription` is taken as the application name. I am using [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058.aspx) as my reference.

#### What I see:

[image: What I see]

#### What I Want to See:

[image: What I want to see]

To achieve the second image, I edited `FileDescription` to **"Test Application"**.

BUT, now in the task manager (and other areas where the description is used),

#### After Editing `FileDescription` to "Test Application":

[image: After editing 'FileDescription' to "Test Application"]

#### Before Editing `FileDescription`:

[image: Before editing 'FileDescription']

I want to know if there's some way to specify to the OS to use the `ProductName` in the first case above (and other similar cases) and `FileDescription` in the second case above (and other similar cases).

Comment: You haven't described the behavior you expected to see, or what's wrong with the observed behavior.

Comment: @jalf, Whoops! Thought that was obvious. Oh well. Edited.

Comment: @jalf, I added screenshots. I hope my question is clearer now.

Comment: That is the way it works. File Description string is not actually the whole description of file. It could be just the string that gives the idea of what your file is related to. I don't think, you can do anything about this.

Comment: @Abhineet, According to [that MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058.aspx), _"File description to be presented to users. This string may be displayed in a list box when the user is choosing files to install?for example, 'Keyboard Driver for AT-Style Keyboards'."_. I think I'm using it in the same way.

Comment: I am not saying that you are using it wrong. I am just saying that I don't think that anything can be done in this case. Anyways let experts answer these.